# Regex to ignore certain occurrences

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a rather sticky little regex issue I could use some help with.

I have a source string that will look like this;

```
%t:H\:i\:s
```

What I am struggling with is trying to figure out what the proper regex statement would be that I can use in a PHP preg_split function that will split the sample string above on the standalone colon ':', but leave the ':' string literal specified sequences out of the split.

So, when successfully completed, the end result would be;

```
array
(
  [0] => %t
  [1] => H\:i\:s
)
```

I'm no guru with regex and have been trying numerous strategies, with no luck yet. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `preg_split("/(?<!\\\\):/", "%t:H\:i\:s")`

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/215705)

Comment: You apparently edited your answer after I chose Sverri's. But seeing as he's being very respectful of your answer, I'll choose yours. Either way, you both were instrumental in helping me solve my issue and I thank you both equally.

Comment: he didn't edit the regex , see the revisions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26685905/revisions)

Comment: @Skittles The answer was edited in order to add a demo. Thank you for choosing it as the best answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you for giving me your support.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go for lookbehind. Just split the input string according to `\b:\b`

```
$string = '%t:H\:i\:s';
$parts  = preg_split('/\b:\b/', $string);
var_dump($parts);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "%t"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "H\:i\:s"
}
```

**Explanation:**

`\b:\b` would match the colon which was preceded and followed by a word character. This would match the colon only in this `t:H` part because there is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) exists between `t` and `:`, `:` and `H`

Comment: I can see where this would prove quite handy. Thank you very much for this answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Match the colon and use a negative look-behind (making sure that the colon does *not* have a backslash in-front of it).

```
$format = '%t:H\:i\:s';
$parts  = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\):/', $format);
var_dump($parts);
```

Comment: Wow! I would never have been able to come up with that on my own. I've always heard that regex was grueling and this just proved it. But it's exactly what I needed. Thank you sooo much!

@Sharanya - Your answer was correct, but it caused a compilation error for me and this one was escaped to fix that. So, I also thank you very much as well. You both are light years ahead of me in regex skills. :)

Comment: @Skittles Regular expressions are actually very easy to learn, once you get past how cryptic it can look.

Comment: Apparently it was edited after I chose yours. So, I apologize to Sharanya if my choice was in error.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use explode shift implode like so

```
$a = explode(':', '%t:H\:i\:s');
$r = array( array_shift( $a ) );
$r[] = implode(':', $a );
```